# How can I pass a tag`s value to a javascript function after an event?

Tags: javascript, events

How can I pass a tag`s value to a javascript function?

this works:

```
onclick="submit(this.value)"
```

but this dosnt work:

```
onclick="submit(document.getElementById("ShortcutID").value)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include quote characters in an attribute value delimited with the same kind of quote characters, you have to represent them with character references.

```
onclick="submit(document.getElementById(&quot;ShortcutID&quot;).value)"
```

Alternatively, use a different kind of quote character.

```
onclick="submit(document.getElementById('ShortcutID').value)"
```

… but try to avoid using intrinsic event attributes and bind your JavaScript event handlers with JavaScript instead. See [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

there is syntax error.

ShortcutID should be enclosed in this 'ShortcutID'

Change this

```
onclick="submit(document.getElementById("ShortcutID").value)"
```

to this

```
onclick="submit(document.getElementById('ShortcutID').value)"
```

Answer (score 0):

> but this dosnt work: onclick="submit(document.getElementById("ShortcutID").value)"

Because you're using double quotes both to delimit the `onclick` attribute and also inside to delimit the JavaScript string. Try:

```
onclick="submit(document.getElementById('ShortcutID').value)"
```

This is why JavaScript allows both single and double quotes for quoting strings.

You can also do it with entities, because remember that the content of an attribute is HTML text just like anything else in the HTML, so:

```
onclick="submit(document.getElementById(&quot;ShortcutID&quot;).value)"
```

The fact that the content is HTML text tends to be problematic when you're doing something non-trivial, which is one reason not to use `onclick="code"` style event handling but rather hooking up the event in code instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have in your code is you are using two sets of double quotes.  To fix this, try this: onclick="submit(document.getElementById('ShortcutID').value)"